# Understanding algorithm for finding a random number

Tags: algorithm, search, random

I'm trying to find the best algorithm for finding a random number between 1-100 using the least number of steps. You can guess a number n using the function `guess(n)`, and you will receive a boolean response true or false. The answer will always be less than the guess you entered into the function if the response is false; if the response is true, it needs to be larger or the guess itself.

Comment: What do you mean by find? How do you determine which half is irrelevant?

Comment: Do you mean binarysearch? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm

Comment: @howard so you will be able to tell if it's not the number at a certain point and it will always be the answer will be less than the number that is guessed. see edits above.

Comment: Your description of `guess()` needs improvement. Does it return `true` when you guess is less or equal to the answer?

Comment: "The answer will always be less that the guess you entered", so I can get it in 1 step: `return guess(2) ? 2 : 1;` If it's 2, then `guess(2)` will be true, and if not, it's less than two. But there's only one number less than 2, so the answer must be 1. Ta-da!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic idea:

First guess(50). Depending on the answer, guess(25) or guess(75).

Answer (score 0):

If you can tell whether your guess is greater or smaller than the random number, then [Binary Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_algorithm) is your friend.

Else, if you can only tell if the numbers match, I would start alternating linear search from the median (50.5) i.e. from 50 to 1 and from 51 to 100 (50, 51, 49, 52...).

Comment: Why would that be any better than just starting with 1 and incrementing up by one?  In either approach, 99 (or 100, depending) would be the worst case "correct" guess.

Comment: @Marvo, for some reason I assumed normal distribution of values, writing the answer. Given that most random generators _try_ to produce uniform distribution, you're right.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure I understand the question, so who knows?  =)